# Django double join via multiple models

Tags: django, orm, django-models

### Situation

I have 3 models. Model A, model B and model C.

```
class A(Model):
    B_id = ForeignKey(B)
    id = IntegerField()
    pub_date = DateField()

class B(Model):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key = True)

class C(Model):
    B_id = ForeignKey(B)
    pub_date = DateField()
    information = TextField()
```

Model A and model C both have a field called `B_id`, which is a foreign key to model B. So there is no direct connection from B to A or C.

### Goal

I'm given an ID from model A. Now I need all informations from C where the pub_date matches the pub_date in A and the B_id matches the B_id in A.

In SQL, this would be a pretty easy query:

```
SELECT C.information FROM A JOIN C USING(B_id, pub_date) WHERE A.id = 1234;
```

But I simply can't figure out how to do this in Django ORM syntax, as a `filter()`-clause only works if there is a direct connection path from C to A.

--

Edit: Please note that there is more than one row in A that matches one id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
 A.objects.filter(B_id__c__pub_date=F('pub_date'))
```

I'm not 100% sure about the capitalization on the filter string, but the `F()` predicate is what you are looking for. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model).

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning it before, but there is more than one row in A that matches one id (I updated the question to reflect this fact). At first I tried to get all the A objects and use an `__in=` filter condition, but then it won't do the comparison pairwise and I might get more results than expected.

Comment: @Danilo  Makes sense looking at your join statement. I just saw "I'm given *an* ID". See my update.

Comment: Cool, thanks :) I had to change the query a little, but the following way it seems to work: `C.objects.filter(B_id__A__id=1234, B_id__A__pub_date=F('pub_date')`. The raw SQL that is generated also looks quite OK, even though an unnecessary inner join was made. But that won't do any harm :)

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I removed my last comment about the query not working. It works perfectly, it was an issue with my database.